# use View Model Providers(ViewModelProviders) in Dagger Dialog Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewmodel, dagger-2

When I Use ViewModelProvider.of in Dagger Fragment i use it with no problem but in Dagger Dialg Fragment i get Error in first Param (Fragment)

**in Code**

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(CreatePlanViewModel::class.java)
```

**Error**

None Of the Following functions can be Called with the arguments supplied.

> of(**Fragment**,ViewmodelProvider.Factory)
>
> of(**FragmentActivity**,VIewModelProvider.Factory)

**Note**
i used activity and this but not working

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are using the `DialogFragment` from the support library:

`android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment` should be imported instead of `android.app.DialogFragment`, because `ViewModelProviders.of()` [expects a `Fragment` from the support library](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders.html#of(android.support.v4.app.Fragment)).

Comment: i am using fragment from androidX with no error Maybe i should Create a Class and enable HasSupportFragmentInjector

Comment: You can use DaggerDialogFragment